# Node JS, Socket.IO Rooms e namespaces

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, namespace, socket.io

Estou desenvolvendo um app android baseado em mapas, que criará salas de bate papo em alguns lugares pré-determinados e em lugares onde os usuários necessitarem.

Fiz algumas pesquisas com mecanismos que poderia usar na minha aplicação e deparei-me com o conceito de **namespaces** e **rooms**. Pelo que percebi os rooms só ficam abertas quando tem pelo menos um socket conectado (correcto ?)

**Quais os conceitos, semelhanças e diferenças entre Rooms e Namespaces?**

Comment: Sua pergunta pode correr o risco de ser fechada pois as respostas podem vir baseadas em opiniões. Por isso sugiro que mude a pergunta de "recomendação" `para minha aplicaçao o que voces recomendam`, para algo como `Quais os conceitos, semelhanças e diferenças entre Rooms e Namespaces`. PS: Também estou curioso quanto às respostas, NodeJS é algo que pretendo dominar em breve.

Comment: na realidade gostaria de "ouvir" mesmo as opnioes , afinal agora que consegui usar ambos, meio que ainda estou em duvida sobre qual usar ... ambos funcionam ... porem acredito que as rooms seram mais viaveis para mim em especifico.... mas mudarei valeu pela dica

Comment: @KaduAmaral como voce tambem estava interessado em sabe achei uma explicaçao muito boa no SO em ingles https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930286/socket-io-rooms-or-namespacing
da uma olhada sanou minhas duvidas hehe

Comment: Show Osvaldo, vou traduzir e postar aqui pra ajudar outras pessoas que precisarem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto é o que *namespaces* e *rooms* tem **em comum** (socket.io v0.9.8 - note que v1.0 foi reescrito completamente, então algumas coisas podem ter mudado):

- Ambos *namespaces* [`io.of('/nsp')`](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io#restricting-yourself-to-a-namespace) e *rooms* [`socket.join('room')`](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms) **são criados do lado do servidor**
- Multiplos *namespaces* e multiplos *rooms* **compartilham a mesma conecção (WebSocket)**
- O servidor **transmitirá mensagens apenas para os clientes** que conectaram a um nsp/room, i.e. o filtro não é apenas no cliente

As **diferenças**:

- ***Namespaces* são conectados ao cliente** usando `io.connect(urlAndNsp)` (o cliente vai ser adicionado ao *namespace* apenas se já existir no servidor)
- ***Rooms* podem "entrar" apenas do lado do servidor** (emborar criando uma API do lado do servidor permite que o cliente entre diretamente)
- ***Namespaces* podem ter [autorização protegida](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing)**
- ***Rooms* não tem suporte a autorização**, mas uma autorização customizada pode ser adicionada, easy-to-create API no servidor, no caso de alguém estar em multiplas *rooms*
- ***Rooms* fazem parte de um *namespace*** (namespace padrão 'global')
- ***Namespaces* são sempre alocados no escopo global**

Para não confundir o conceito com o nome (room or namespace), Vou usar compartimento para me referir ao conceito, e os outros dois nomes para a imlpementação do conceito. Então:

- Se você precisa de autorização por compartimento, *namespaces* deve ser o caminho mais fácil a se tomar
- Se você quer hierarquizar os compartimento em camadas (2 camadas no máximo), use um combo namespace/room
- Se o seu *client-side app* consiste em partes diferentes que (não se preocupam com compartimentos, mas) precisam ser separadas uma da outra, use *namespaces*.

Um último exemplo seria um aplicativo cliente grande onde diferentes módulos, talvez desenvolvidos separadamente (por exemplo, terceiros), cada um usando o socket.io de forma independente, estão sendo usados no mesmo aplicativo e querem compartilhar uma única conexão de rede.

Não tendo realmente comparado isso, parece-me se você precisa apenas de compartimentos simples em seu projeto para separar e agrupar mensagens, qualquer um ficará bom.

Não tenho certeza se isso responde sua pergunta, mas a pesquisa que conduziu a essa resposta, pelo menos, me ajudou a ver mais claro.

---

<sub>Esta resposta é uma tradução livre da [resposta do Eugene Beresovsky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751954/3497987) a uma pergunta semelhante feita no StackOverflow</sub>